# What is the difference between gerritcodereview/gerrit:X.X.X and gerritcodereview/gerrit:X.X.X-ubuntuXX?

Tags: docker, gerrit

I am going to install gerrit using docker images.
And I found some similar images in gerrit dockerhub (https://hub.docker.com/r/gerritcodereview/gerrit)

What is the difference between gerritcodereview/gerrit:X.X.X and gerritcodereview/gerrit:X.X.X-ubuntu ?

If I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 as OS, should I use the image gerritcodereview/gerrit:X.X.X-ubuntu18?

Answer (score 1):

The `-distributionXX` specifies the distribution the image is based on. A quick look at `gerritcodereview`'s Docker Hub page shows that `gerritcodereview:3.3.0` is the same image as `gerritcodereview:3.3.0-centos8`.

The version without a specified distribution can be considered the developer's preferred version - if you don't need a specific distribution, use this one. But if you need the image to be based on a specific distribution, which usually means you're using that image as a base for an image you are building, you can use the `-distributionXX` tag. This guarantees, for example, that you'll know which package manager you have to use to install any additional dependencies.